# Button only clickable after X seconds

Tags: android, button, delay, countdown

I am trying to create a button which is only clickable after for example 3 seconds. It should display a countdown, when 0 is reached, one can click the button and an action gets performed.
For example when the Activity gets called, the button displays a "3" first and counts down to "0", only then one can click on the button.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Use counter first and count 3 seconds, till that set `clickable=false` to button and after 3 seconds set it to true.

Comment: I need to build a thread for that first, right? Or does an activity has an implemented update method which is able to count seconds?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should use `CountDownTimer` for that:

```
timer = new CountDownTimer( 3000, 1000 ) {
  @Override public void onTick( long millisUntilFinished ) {
    button.setText( "count down " + millisUntilFinished );
  }
  @Override public void onFinish() { 
    button.setOnClickListener( onClickListener );
  }
};
```

somewhere down below:

```
timer.start()
```

Comment: Going to try that out, thanks for the reply

Don't forget the (int) cast in front of millisUntilFinished on the setText() method!

Comment: yeah, if you want to print the countdown strings, you shall make something like `button.setText( "count down " + Math.floor( millisUntilFinished / 1000 ) );`

Answer (score 5):

```
  button.setEnabled(false);

  new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         button.setText("Wait for " + (millisUntilFinished / 1000) + " seconds");
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         button.setEnabled(true);
         button.setText("Press me!");
     }
  }.start();
```